# Create an output array that contains all distinct characters in an array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my first question here, please bear with me!

I'm working on learning PHP and have some problems I'm trying to solve. I have no previous PHP experience, so putting together a solution to this question has been incredibly difficult.

Here is the question:
$person_array = array('Leanna', 'derek', 'Lisa', 'John', 'Lancelot', 'Michael', 'Norman', 'Lawrence of Arabia');

- Create an output array that contains all distinct characters (Uppercase and Lowercase) from the strings contained within the array above. Use only the str_split function and any of the Array functions to do so.

Here's what I'm *thinking*, it obviously doesn't work and I have no idea what to do to make it work:

```
$result = "";

foreach($person_array as $name){ 
    $char = str_split($name)
    foreach($char as $eval){
        if($result === $eval){
            return "";
        }
        else{
            $result = $eval;
        }
    }
}

print $result;
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use 'foreach' loops and 'if' statements to answer this question?  Have you studied / covered the 'array_map' and the 'array_reduce' functions?

Comment: Yes, I can use those functions 

I haven't studied or covered those functions yet, unfortunately. Those are  definitely something I should look into

Comment: You can use 'foreach' loops to do the exact same actions that those functions do. I am just trying to find out what is expected of you by the person who set the question.

Comment: Thank you! I really want to understand the code so would be great if you could share the answer with me. Will the answer follow the guidelines you stated above? I've found a way that works, but feel it's important to see different methods!

Comment: Here is how i did the _`foreach`_ loop answer to this challenge: [What are the distinct characters in an array of words?](https://eval.in/private/4236c9a45b3fcd) The 'array_map' and 'array_reduce' answers are based on this. Feedback is welcome.

Comment: Here is the _array_map & array_reduce_ version: [contains all distinct characters in an array](https://eval.in/private/17e03160fbef13).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend joining all the elements in the array and going from there. The code will look nicer with one less cycle, although it should be similar performance wise.

```
$all_characters = implode('', $person_array);
$unique_characters = [];

foreach($all_characters as $char) {
  if(!in_array($char, $unique_characters)) {
    $unique_characters[] = $char;
  }
}
```

Comment: Explicitly the question says: "Use only the str_split function and any of the Array functions to do so."

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done. Can you point what's wrong before downvoting?

Comment: are you right! I understand without any array function. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the array and through the strings as array, make a new array and get the keys with `array_keys()` take a look ;-)

```
<?php

$person_array = array('Leanna', 'derek', 'Lisa', 'John', 'Lancelot', 'Michael', 'Norman', 'Lawrence of Arabia');
$newArray = array();

foreach($person_array as $values) {
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($values); $i++) {
        $newArray[$values[$i]] = '';
    }
}

print_r(array_keys($newArray));

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => L
    [1] => e
    [2] => a
    [3] => n
    [4] => d
    [5] => r
    [6] => k
    [7] => i
    [8] => s
    [9] => J
    [10] => o
    [11] => h
    [12] => c
    [13] => l
    [14] => t
    [15] => M
    [16] => N
    [17] => m
    [18] => w
    [19] =>  
    [20] => f
    [21] => A
    [22] => b
)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the array_unique function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Also here is the corrected code:

```
$result = array();

foreach($person_array as $name){ 
    if( !in_array($name,$result) )
      $result[] = $name;
}

print ($result);
```

OR

```
$result = array_unique($person_array);
```

Comment: This will create an array of unique elements from the original array, not what it's intended. OP wants an array with unique characters.